# Checking VP9 hardware video decode support on Apple Silicon

Tags: swift, codec, hardware-acceleration, video-toolbox, vp9

I'm trying to check whether a device running on Apple Silicon supports hardware video decode of VP9.

I know empirically (from using Chrome and Safari) that `VP9` decode is supported in hardware on Apple Silicon, however, using the basic check below I get false for `VP9`.

FWIW it shows true for `H.264`.

Is my code missing something? - I'm testing on an M1 Max MBP using the latest release of Ventura (`13.5.2 (22G91)`).

I did think maybe it's private to big players like Google, but the `kCMVideoCodecType_VP9` constant exists...

```
class HardwareDecProfiler {

    func hardwareDecodeSupported(codec: CMVideoCodecType) -> Bool {
        return VTIsHardwareDecodeSupported(codec)
    }

    func runChecks() {
        let vp9Support = self.hardwareDecodeSupported(codec: kCMVideoCodecType_VP9)
        print("VP9 hardware decoding support check: \(vp9Support)")
    }
}


//prints: VP9 hardware decoding support check: false
```

Comment: Hmm. The Chromium source looks the same (`VTIsHardwareDecodeSupported(kCMVideoCodecType_VP9)`) from https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/42ff7b720ac8b59e20e81abed730d5c025b24c56/media/gpu/mac/vt_video_decode_accelerator_mac.cc#L2309

Comment: yep indeed, noticed that, is there a sandbox privilege or something maybe?

Comment: Looks like some whacky entitlement is required (looking at the YouTube binary for iOS): com.apple.developer.coremedia.allow-alternate-video-decoder-selection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to call `VTRegisterSupplementalVideoDecoderIfAvailable(kCMVideoCodecType_VP9)` first, to enable VP9 hardware decode support for the process.